# Stopping Solr (Jetty) using the STOP PORT

Tags: security, jetty

I can stop Jetty from the command line like this:

```
java -DSTOP.PORT=8080 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar --stop
```

Is it possible to stop Jetty using telnet or netcat to send the stop key to the stop port? I tried and it did not work, but maybe you know something I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple tcp server running on your `STOP.PORT`.

Connect to it, send the STOP.KEY with a linefeed (`\n`).
Then send one of the following commands ...

- `forcestop\n`
- `stopexit\n`
- `exit\n`
- `status\n`

See behaviors of those commands at [`ShutdownMonitor.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.12.v20180830/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ShutdownMonitor.java#L335-L410)

Should be able to do that with an echo to `netcat`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you add the command to your answer, please? I'm trying to run `echo -en 'solrrocks\nstopexit\n' | nc 127.0.0.1 7983` and SOLR still continues to run.